# To get AES-256 encryption, do I just provide a 256-bit key?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I'd like to encrypt some data prior to storage. I'm a little confused about how I ensure that I have 256 bit encryption.

If I'm using `AesCryptoServiceProvider` for example, do I simply need to supply a key of the correct length? Or do I need to set the `KeySize`, or `LegalKeySizes` property?

Comment: Looking in reflector, you should just be able to supply a 32-byte key, but I hope someone can find a reference on MSDN.

Comment: It's the height of modesty to answer with a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the KeySize equals to one of the LegalKeySizes. Key property will throw an exception if you try try to set it with illegal-size key. I think KeySize setter is usefull when you want to change key size in runtime. Otherwise the only Key property is enough.

Comment: I guess there's no way for me to verify any answer here. How the hell can I tell if my data has been encrypted with the correct 256 key and algorithm? So I'll mark you correct with the limited level of certainly I can have.

Comment: Thanks, but what the problem if your data encrypted with 256 key? Set KeySize = KeySize[value for 256bit], set Key=your_265_key and everything should work fine. Or i'm missing something?

Comment: Or if you want to know what key size was used for the given cyphertext having the only cyphertext, then i think it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a key (32 bytes) and IV (16 bytes). KeySize is set automatically.